# creating own npx command - not running/does nothing

Tags: npm, npx

I've created my own npx command following this article as a guide: https://www.danielbischoff.com/blog/2018-09-23--cli-scripts-with-npm/

The project I have is typescript and I am using tsc to transpile. My tsconfig looks like this:

```html
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "declaration": true,
        "declarationDir": "build",
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "umd" ,
        "strict": true,
        "esModuleInterop",
        "outDir": "build",
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
    },
    "types": ["node"],
    "typeRoots": ["../node_modules/@types"],
    "include": ["src/**/*"],
    "exclude": ["node_modules", "build"]
}
```

In package.json, I have properties for bin and main like so:

```html
  "main": "./build/index.js",
  "bin": "./build/index.js",
```

When testing locally, if I run "npx ." from the same level as the package.json, the command I created will run as expected.

However, once it is published into my private npm registry and I try running the command, e.g. npx my-command, it doesn't do anything - apart from display: npx: installed 290 in 25.638s.

The command then finishes running, with no errors.

Any ideas on what might be causing this? I would have expected it to work. If I do an npm install of that package into a project, I am able to go into the directory and run the command with: node ./build/src/index.js and it runs without issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer to my problem - I was missing the shebang statement from the entry file:

#!/usr/bin/env node

Comment: Thanks for following up! This helped me save hours of poor googling :)